# How to make the bottom of each column in alignment for columns page layout

Tags: c#, .net, itext, itext7

I'm using ColumnDocumentRenderer to draw content in two columns.

Below are the codes.

```
public void ManipulatePdf(string dest)
{
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);
    doc.SetMargins(55f, 55f, 45f, 55f);

    var interval = 20f;
    var columnWidth = (doc.GetPdfDocument().GetDefaultPageSize().GetWidth() - 110 - interval) / 2;
    var pageHeight = doc.GetPdfDocument().GetDefaultPageSize().GetHeight() - 110;

    var baseText = "We have seen too many reports, too many words, too many good intentions, too many families torn apart, and too many excruciatingly painful deaths to see yet more delays in taking collective action.";

    var pTitle = new Paragraph(baseText);
    pTitle.SetFontSize(20);
    pTitle.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED);

    doc.Add(pTitle);

    var currentYLine = doc.GetRenderer().GetCurrentArea().GetBBox().GetTop();
    Rectangle[] columns = {
            new Rectangle(55, 55,
            columnWidth,
            currentYLine - 55),
            new Rectangle(55 + columnWidth + interval, 55,
            columnWidth,
            currentYLine - 55) };
    doc.SetRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(doc, columns));

    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        var text = baseText;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            text += " Additional Text. ";
        }
        var p = new Paragraph(text);
        p.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED);
        doc.Add(p);
        if (i == 6)
        {
            var tp = new Paragraph("Introduction");
            tp.SetFontSize(20);
            tp.SetMarginTop(50);
            tp.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED);
            doc.Add(tp);
        }
    }
    doc.Close();

}
```

Below is the created PDF:

[image: PDF File]

Please take a look at the red line in this screenshot, my question is that how to make bottom of two columns alignment in a straight line?

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Well, if we align the bottoms of the two columns then we need to shift some content and other lines will not be aligned - so where do you want to get extra space from or which lines do you want to squeeze to achieve your goal?

Comment: Hi Alexey, actually it's just a simple example, the pdf page may contains title, image or table, not just text paragraph. What I want is how to calculate the extra space of the bottom so I can squeeze somewhere ( for example, from the 'Introduction' title) to achieve the goal.

Comment: So you want to just know the difference between the vertical positions of the last two lines but you will then "know" which content adjust and how, right? You don't expect automatic algorithm to handle that?

Comment: Hi Alexey, I think automatic algorithm is necessary, as I want to create the whole pdf automatically without any human intervention. From my understanding, if I can calculate the vertical positions difference in advance then the difference can be clear by adjusting some line spacing or paragraph margin.

Comment: Let's say your font size is 10pt. The difference between last two lines in two columns is 9.5pt. The algorithm adjusts the line spacing of some two lines and adds 9.5pt there. Would the result be acceptable to you? I think it will look very weird.

Comment: Hi Alexey, yes it will looks weird and unacceptable. maybe I can adjust more lines and paragraph margins to clear 9.5pt difference smoothly. What's your opinion? Could you please provide some clew to meet this requirement? Thanks!

Comment: What I am saying is that it looks like you are not 100% sure what you want the algorithm to do :) There is no such functionality in iText unfortunately. It is possible to get the difference between the positions of the bottom lines but the thing is that you will have to decide how to reflow the content yourself

Comment: Hi Alexey, indeed I'm a litter confused. You mentioned reflow the content, but I'm not sure it can be implemented. What I think is that find some way to calculate the difference between the positions of the bottom lines before flowing the content, then I can handle and clear the difference in the process of page rendering.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments to the original question, algorithm to auto-align the bottom lines does not exist in iText and defining its behavior turned out to be tricky even for the person asking the question.

However, it is possible to calculate the difference between the vertical positions of the bottom lines when the document is being rendered and then you can correct the content and create another document with proper layout.

Here is the example implementation which analyzes the positions of the content when it's being drawn on the document:

```
class CustomColumnDocumentRenderer : ColumnDocumentRenderer {
    public CustomColumnDocumentRenderer(Document document, Rectangle[] columns) : base(document, columns) {
    }

    public CustomColumnDocumentRenderer(Document document, bool immediateFlush, Rectangle[] columns) : base(document, immediateFlush, columns) {
    }
    
    IDictionary<int, float> leftColumnBottom = new Dictionary<int, float>();
    IDictionary<int, float> rightColumnBottom = new Dictionary<int, float>();

    protected override void FlushSingleRenderer(IRenderer resultRenderer) {
        TraverseRecursively(resultRenderer, leftColumnBottom, rightColumnBottom);
        
        base.FlushSingleRenderer(resultRenderer);
    }
    
    void TraverseRecursively(IRenderer child, IDictionary<int, float> leftColumnBottom, IDictionary<int, float> rightColumnBottom) {
        if (child is LineRenderer) {
            int page = child.GetOccupiedArea().GetPageNumber();
            if (!leftColumnBottom.ContainsKey(page)) {
                leftColumnBottom[page] = 1000;
            }

            if (!rightColumnBottom.ContainsKey(page)) {
                rightColumnBottom[page] = 1000;
            }

            bool isLeftColumn = !(child.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().GetX() > PageSize.A4.GetWidth() / 2);

            if (isLeftColumn) {
                leftColumnBottom[page] =
                    Math.Min(leftColumnBottom[page], child.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().GetBottom());
            } else {
                rightColumnBottom[page] = Math.Min(rightColumnBottom[page],
                    child.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().GetBottom());
            }
        } else {
            foreach (IRenderer ownChild in (child is ParagraphRenderer ? (((ParagraphRenderer)child).GetLines().Cast<IRenderer>()) : child.GetChildRenderers())) {
                TraverseRecursively(ownChild, leftColumnBottom, rightColumnBottom);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<float> getDiffs() {
        List<float> ans = new List<float>();
        foreach (int pageNum in leftColumnBottom.Keys) {
            ans.Add(leftColumnBottom[pageNum] - rightColumnBottom[pageNum]);
        }

        return ans;
    }
}
```

To use it, make sure to pass the customized document renderer to the `Document` instance:

```
CustomColumnDocumentRenderer renderer = new CustomColumnDocumentRenderer(doc, true, columns);        
doc.SetRenderer(renderer);
```

Then you can get page-by-page diffs:

```
Console.WriteLine(renderer.getDiffs()[0]);
```